# Should I concern about Linux driver for headset?

Tags: linux, drivers, audio, usb-audio

I was thinking about buying Logitech G430 headset. However, the producer mentions windows operating system only. As my personal experience even if only windows garbage drivers(or I call them fancy inter-mediator dialogs rather than drivers) are supported, I have not had any problem with Linux. Every device that I have had till now has worked fine with Linux except for a printer that hangs when printing big image in Linux but not windows. However, to avoid cost damage here, I want to make sure how much should I concern about the drivers when Linux is not mentioned to be supported directly?

[image]

Comment: @garethTheRed, The point is that when the driver is not supported directly by the company, some features are dismissed. Then an expensive headset might have performance of a cheap one.

Comment: From [www.linux-hardware.com](http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/uk/2014-11-16-logitech-g430-gaming-headset-surround-sound-usb): _"Although the headset and the microphone can be used under Linux, the headset does not support 7.1 Surround Sound under Linux."_

Comment: Aparenttly 7.1 is possible under Ubuntu 14.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/491626/surround-sound-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-logitech-g430